# To prove topologically not same

Tags: general-topology

The sets

- $A=\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}  \;|\; xy=0 \text{ and } x+y \geq 0 \}$
- $B=\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}  \;|\; xy=0 \} $

are not homeomorphic.

In $A$ if we remove the origin  it becomes $2$ pieces, in $ B$  it comes $4$.

Is there any other way to prove this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you desperately want a different way:
Clearly, $A$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R$ via $(x,y)\mapsto x-y$.

In $B$, we have the points $b_1=(1,0)$, $b_2=(0,1)$, $b_3=(-1,0)$.
Clearly, for any two of these, we find a path between them that does not contain the third.
Assume $f\colon B\to\Bbb R$ is a homeomorphism and let $a_i=f(b_i)$.
In $\Bbb R$, every path from the smallest to the largest of the $a_i$ passes through the third, contradiction.

Comment: How this $(x,y)\mapsto x-y$ can be invertible? since $(6,4)$ and $ (4,2)$ have the same image!

Comment: @The_lost neither of those points are in $A$. It is only invertible for points that are actually in $A$. The inverse is $$x \mapsto \begin{cases}(x,0), & x\ge 0 \\ (0,-x), & x<0\end{cases}$$

Comment: @InterstellarProbe So clear, thank you